# Why are there two different feedbacks in this battery simulator design?

Tags: feedback, compensation

I am trying to understand this **LT1970 Battery Simulator Design** and I could not figure out what is the point of two different feedback legs in this circuit? I have tried AC analysis but could not get helpful results. I would appreciate any help.

[image: LT1970 Battery Simulator Circuit]

Comment: Where did you take that schematic from? I don't see it in the datasheet, or its test jig in LTspice. Maybe the authors can provide an answer?

Comment: Presumably to model different aspects of the battery performance. One FB path involves the sense resistor and thus depends on load current, the other does not.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I could not reach the authors.

Answer (score 0):

I think R116 and C45 is not there for feedback but for compensation. Since opamps output is inductive and any capacitive load leads an oscillation. To compensate the oscillation there is a capacitor (C45).

Comment: Then what's `C43`'s purpose? "*opamps output is inductive*" -- can you prove this? Also, don't forget that this site is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. It might help you to [take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: https://www.edn.com/compensation-techniques-for-driving-large-capacitance-loads-with-high-speed-amplifiers/ I referred this site and comment "opamps output is inductive". C43 might correct the feedback. And about "Also, don't forget that this site is not a forum, it's a Q&A site" I could not really understand what you mean. I am not supposed to answer my question? or it is not allowed to say I think?

Comment: The inductive part just means thare is a phase lag, and the capacitor might cancel with a phase lead. But that still leaves the problem of `C43`. One of them will compensate the phase, alright, but what about the other? What about the fact that both feedback resistors and capacitors are very close in value? Why use two networks, instead of one? You are very much allowed to answer your own question, but it seems that you're not very convinced of your own answer, so I though (mea culpa) that you're after confirmation, as opposed to posting a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, C43 is still problematic. Thank you.